# Linq query involving 4 joined tables, to a many to many table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to return true when any record either has an Indemnity type of bond, or has the bond waived. I think because of the way inner joins are happening this is not working.

```
var HasBondorWaived = (from a in context.Allocations
                       join p in context.Permits on a.PermitGUID equals p.GUID
                       join i in context.Indemnities on a.IndemnityGUID equals i.GUID
                       join t in context.IndemnityTypes on a.IndemnityAreaTypeGUID equals t.GUID
                       where (p.GUID.Equals(PermitGuid)
                       && (t.Description.Equals("Performance Bonds") || t.Description.Equals("Payment Bonds")))
                       || p.BondRequirementWaived where p.GUID.Equals(PermitGuid)
                       select a).Any();
return HasBondorWaived;
```

I'm getting closer. My validation is now working correctly in the case of "Performance Bond" or "Payment Bond", but is not working in the case of BondRequirementWaved. This is a bool in the EF, and a bit in SQL server. In the case of BondRequirementWaved, it is returning false.

```
using (var context = new KEPTEntities())
        {
            var HasBondorWaived = (from a in context.Allocations
                                   join p in context.Permits on a.PermitGUID equals p.GUID
                                   join i in context.Indemnities on a.IndemnityGUID equals i.GUID
                                   join t in context.IndemnityTypes on i.IndemnityTypeGUID equals t.GUID
                                   where (p.GUID.Equals(PermitGuid) 
                                   && (t.Description.Equals("Performance Bonds") 
                                   || t.Description.Equals("Payment Bonds") 
                                   || p.BondRequirementWaived))
                                   select a).Any();
            return HasBondorWaived;
```

Comment: I think the where is only working against the 4th join.  You close parenthesis is in the wrong place for open parenthesis in front of the from.  See example on following webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second where clause won't work as you expect.  You need to remove it.

You probably want this:

```
where (p.GUID.Equals(PermitGuid)
&& (t.Description.Equals("Performance Bonds") || t.Description.Equals("Payment Bonds")
|| p.BondRequirementWaived))
```

Assuming you have navigation properties set up, this is much cleaner:

```
var HasBondorWaived=context.Allocations
  .Where(a=>a.Permits.GUID.Equals(PermitGuid))
  .Any(a=>a.Permits.BondRequirementWaived || 
    a.Indemnities.Any(i=>i.IdemnityType.Description=="Performance Bonds" || i.IdemnityType.Description=="Payment Bonds"));
```

Kind of hard to see what you actually asking for, but I think that is what you want based on your question and without a clear entity model.

Comment: I think this is very close, but I can't seem to get it working. It's returning false in every case. I do not have the navigation properties, so I cannot use the cleaner suggestion.

Comment: What is the relationships like between the tables? Are they all 1:1, 1:0-1, or 1:*?